# laravel 8 - migrate:rollback with path parameter doesn't find migration

Tags: php, laravel, database, migration, laravel-8

This is my current `migrations` table in database:

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| id | migration                                                           | batch |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+

{ ...other migations entry...}

| 34 | 2024_02_07_055842_create_work_preferences_table                     |     6 |
| 43 | 2024_02_25_081657_add_academy_start_date_column_to_accounts_table   |     7 |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

I want to rollback `2024_02_07_055842_create_work_preferences_table` this migartion only. I ran following command, but didn't work:

```
$ php artisan migrate:rollback --path=database/migrations/2024_02_07_055842_create_work_preferences_table.php

Migration not found: 2024_02_25_081657_add_academy_start_date_column_to_accounts_table
```

Help me to understand how rollback works with path parameter.
I also need to do it in production environment. What is the best way to rollback in production?

**Please note that, I don't want to drop all tables, as there exists a lots of data.**

Comment: instead of rollback, why create a new migration file? then copy both the up and down of `create_work_preferences_table` to new migration file but swapped!

Comment: With this, the migration history is still the same in other environments (e,g pull on other local)

Comment: rollback method only executes the `down` of the migration file you wish to rollback.

Comment: I understand creating a new migration file will serve as a solution to rollback, but I want to understand how rollback actually works in Laravel with path parameter.